# {z}/{x}/{y} tiles for Belgium names only

Tags: leaflet, tiles

Right now I have a leaflet map, with GEOJSON layers rendered on top of them, behind that I render {z}/{x}/{y} tiles that only displays names of countries, cities, and so on.

The thing is, that everything that falls outside Belgium, i don't really want to see on the map.
I searched a lot but can't find one with only names

[image]

That why I wondering if there are any free name layers from ONLY belgium on the internet?

If not, is it hard to make one?

Comment: Are name tiles raster or vector tiles?

Comment: The ones i'm using are vector

Comment: Then it's usually possible to filter the layer to show only desired features. Can you please edit your question and add relevant existing code.